# trying to do a google search with c and user input and url keeps being put on a new line

Tags: c

I am trying to take in a user input and open up a google search based on that user input, but when I go to print the URL saved in `temp` to see if it concatenated properly it prints them on separate lines.

```
char google[] = "start https:";

char first_half[] = "www.google.com/search?biw=1368&bih=776&ei=Mn6FW9nHDpKyzwKC8prQDw&q=";
char mid_section[] = "&oq=";
char last_half[] = "&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1l2j0i67k1l3j0i131i67k1j0i67k1l4.4561.8093.0.8902.33.11.0.0.0.0.344.826.0j1j0j2.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..30.3.748.6..0i22i30k1.231.EO1qOJO2LYY";

char user[100];

puts("What would you like to search? ");
getchar();
fgets(user, sizeof(user), stdin);

char temp[sizeof(google) + sizeof(first_half) + sizeof(mid_section) + sizeof(last_half)];

strcpy(temp, google);
strcat(temp, first_half);
strcat(temp, user);
strcat(temp, mid_section);
strcat(temp, user);
strcat(temp, last_half);

printf("%s", temp);
```

Comment: Without looking too much at your code using `strcat()` like that indicates that you don't know c very much. Also `sizeof()` may not be doing what you think, it's certainly not allocating less space.

Comment: You have concatenated `user` twice but not allowed any length at all - nor for the terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: Use `snprintf()` and consider that `sizeof` a array of `char` that was initialized with a string literal will include the `null` terminator. So the correct length of a string that is initialized like that is `sizeof(string) - 1`, it's the same as `strlen(string)` which is the correct way to compute the length of a string. If they weren't `char` arrays then the code would be very wrong.

Comment: @WeatherVane The OP used `sizeof` and that will include each of the `null` terminators of all the involved strings. But certainly did not allocate space for the `user`.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi good point.

Comment: Note that all that is needed to search google is `google.com/search?q=<query here>`; the other info in the URL can be omitted

Comment: I bet that if you used `snprintf` to put everything together into `temp`, and passed in the size that you think you need, that `snprintf` will return a larger value than you're expecting.

Comment: I have got it working, ty to all. I am still learning a lot about c.